# Compare list of strings based on their rank - JavaScript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've three drop down lists in my page - `Rating1`, `Rating2` and `OverallRating`.

The dropdown list values are `High`, `Low` and `Medium`. Based on the rating selected in `Rating1` and `Rating2` I've to set the rating for `OverallRating` automatically. I've to set the *lowest* of the two ratings - `Rating1` and `Rating2`.

For example -

If `Rating1 == Medium` and `Rating 2 == High`; Then `OverallRating = Medium`

How can I do this in javaScript/jQuery? How to assign some kind of weight/rank for the string and compare them?

Note: For simplicity purpose I've taken only three values High, Low, Medium. In reality I've 7-8 options in the dropdown.

Comment: Please post your _real_ markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array of strings that is ordered by relative value. Assuming `dd1`, `dd2` and `dd3` are the three drop-downs:

```
var ratings = ["Low", "Medium", "High"];
var index = Math.min(ratings.indexOf($(dd1).val()), ratings.indexOf($(dd2).val()));
$(dd3).val(ratings[index]);
```

Comment: @NLV I made a slight blunder. Please use the version I have just updated to.